# How to confirm you are not having memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

So..I am trying to write my first destructor. I have sth, but I don't know if it is actually doing what it supposed to do.

I have a linear linked list where every node has 3 dynamically allocated char arrays and a next pointer(`heads`) to another linked list that also has 1 dynamic char array. In other words the data structure is a linked list of linked list.  This is what I wrote:

```
nodea * tempa = heada;//create a new node to
nodesongs *temps=heada->heads;

while(heada)// while the list is not empty
{

        tempa= heada ->nexta;// traverse the list
        delete [] heada->dataa.name ;
        delete [] heada->dataa.story ;
        delete [] heada->dataa.description ;

        while(heada->heads)
        {
                temps = heada ->heads->nexts;
                delete[] heada->heads->datas.title;
                delete heada->heads;
                heada->heads = temps;
        }
      delete heada;
      heada = tempa;

}
```

I'd appreciate if you have a look at it and also would like to know if there is a common way people test their codes for memory leaks?

Comment: In modern C++, we handle memory with smart pointers and STL containers. doing so will almost eliminate any chances of memory leaks. your code is good for studying low-level, past practices of memory management. this is important, but this code shouldn't pass any modern code review.

Comment: Don't use new/delete! Ex: `delete [] heada->dataa.name ;`So you have a string. Why don't you use std::string?

Comment: Don't delete the `heada` members. That's the job of the destructor when you call `delete heada`. Use a C++ data type for the members, then you don't have to care for deletion.

Comment: @manni66 I am not allowed to :( No strings, no vectors, no global variables, no mid function return statements.

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: Why can't you use STL objects like strings?

Comment: @LucAux In that case, `new` and `new[]` should only exist in constructors, directly initialising a member, always with a corresponding `delete` or `delete[]` in the destructor. There should be **no flow control** in those.

Comment: You could always have the 'strings' character arrays rather than pointers.   Has the up side that you don't have to worry about memory allocation; The down side is that there's a max string length and uses a bit more memory.

Comment: @manni66 Haha yes, she is very controversial in the department too. In her defense she is 'laying the foundations' of C++. But she generally doesn't like vectors. Other than she is actually a dedicated teacher. She writes extensive lab manuals every semester.

Comment: _'laying the foundations' of C++_ std::string **is foundation**!

Comment: if you cannot use `std::string` write a simplified `MyString`. You shouldn't have to handle manually string memory in your list.

Comment: if You write MyString, study "rule of 3" and "rule of 5"

Comment: @Jarod42 this.  You'll learn about how to make a smart pointer and what it does;  This has value.  What the teacher thinks they're teaching you (about using pointers etc) has less.

Comment: `no mid function return statements.` What on earth? I completely understand that manual memory management should be taught (except, perhaps not to beginners), but this "rule" seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to confirm you are not having memory leaks?

There is no standard way for a C++ program to inspect its own state and find a memory leak.

There are however programming tools that can detect if a particular execution has leaked memory. These can tell you what was leaked, but that doesn't necessarily help you understand *why* it was leaked.

What you can do is analyse the program that you've written, and logically deduce whether any manually allocated memory would be leaked. This is extremely difficult to do in general (which is why compilers cannot do it for you), but it can become manageable if you follow best practices:

- Never manage memory manually (99,99% chance that you don't need to)

  1. Never call `new`, nor `malloc`
  2. Always wrap owned pointers in smart pointers immediately after receiving them
  3. Always read the documentation of the libraries that you use. If a function gives you a bare pointer, double check whether you're responsible for disposing it; if you are, see 2.

     - This is typical when dealing with libraries that have a C API. Sometimes also with old or badly designed C++ API's.
- If you do manage memory manually (but don't, because you don't need to)

  - Only ever do so in [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) fashion

    4. The owning pointer should be a private member of a class. This encapsulation reduces the scope that you have to analyse from the entire program to the member functions of this class.

       - Don't ever return references or pointers to this member, only copies (maybe not even that). Returning a reference would break the encapsulation (only non-const references, but there is no *point* in returning a pointer by const reference).
    5. Class invariant: The pointer must always point to null or a valid dynamically allocated object; No other instance of the class may point to this object.

       - If the member is allowed to not point to a valid dynamically allocated object (or null), then destructor of an object in such state would have undefined behaviour.
       - If several objects were allowed to own the same pointer, then destroying one would cause the other object to violate the invariant about pointing to valid object.
       - The implicit copy/move constructor and assignment operator perform a shallow copy which would cause violation of these invariants. Therefore we must follow the [rule of 3 (or 5)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)
    6. The destructor of the class has to delete the pointer
    7. Any single time that member is assigned, either delete to old value, or "transfer" its ownership to another object (unless the pointer has an unspecified value, which it can only be within a constructor due to 5.). These assignments are where you're most likely to accidentally leak memory.
    8. Only have at most 1 owned bare pointer per class. Use nested classes if necessary. This suggestion is to make it possible / easier to guarantee [exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). Lack of exception safety is the more subtle way to leak memory.

---

About your code, let us assume that you have to manage memory manually, to learn how to do it, so my suggestions 1 and 2 are not an option:

> ```
> delete [] heada->dataa.name ;
> delete [] heada->dataa.story ;
> ```

Bad 1: Don't delete pointers owned by other objects. This violates my suggestion 6. Delete in the destructor of that object instead.

Bad 2: During the lifetime of the container object (`*heada`), don't let the pointers point to an object that was deleted This is a consequence of Bad 1. and violates my suggestion 5.

Bad 3: Don't have multiple bare owning pointers in a single object. This violates my suggestion 8.

Answer (score 2):

There is no definitive way (see e.g. [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)), however:

- study the C++11 standard, and prefer standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (such as [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)s), standard types (such as [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)s)  and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)s)
- be aware of, and always follow, the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)
- use existing debugging tools such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [GCC instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) (notably its [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)).

In some cases, using some (or thinking in terms of) [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) can be helpful. Sometimes coding your own marking GC is easy and worthwhile. See also [Boehm's GC](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/). BTW, sometimes C++ is not the best language for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Comment expanded to an answer:

You should strive to write code where memory leaks are **not possible**, and this is reasonably achievable with some discipline. If you are not allowed to use things in `namespace std`, then write facsimilies of your own.

E.g. the only place that uses `new`:

```
template<typename T>
struct pointer
{
  template<typename ... TArgs>
  pointer(TArgs&&... targs) : p(new T(targs...)) {}
  pointer(const pointer & other) = delete;
  pointer& operator=(const pointer & other) = delete;
  pointer(pointer && other) : p(other.p) { other.p = nullptr; }
  pointer& operator=(pointer && other) { std::swap(this->p, other.p); }
  ~pointer { delete p; }
  T& operator*() { return *p; }
  T* operator->() { return *p; }
private:
  T * p = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the comments are right about 'use smart pointers' they don't help you find what you're looking for.

Since it's platform dependant, the tool you're looking for is a tool called a memory profiler.

There's a few available, some paid, some not, and most platform specific.  One that I can recommend if you're on Linux though is valgrind.